# Custom ArrayAdapter in android updating the view of 1st entry only in ListActivity

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity showing a list of items and there is a ImageView at the right end of each item which shows an arrow icon at the beginning.After a certain button press I want to replace those arrow icons with a delete icon.For this I have changed the ArrayAdapter of the ListView and called notifyDataSetChanged().In the ArrayAdapter's getView method I have set the ImageResource for the ImageView but the change is not showing on the list only the 1st entry has a changed icon.

Here is the ArrayAdapter code:

```
private class CCAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CCcenter>{

    ArrayList<CCcenter> items;
    int mode;
    public CCAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CCcenter> Items,int m) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, Items);
        this.items=Items;
        this.mode=m;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.lisitem, null);
            }
            final CCcenter o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {

                    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ttl_txt);
                    TextView desc=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.desc_txt);
                    TextView dist=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dist_txt);
                    ImageView icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lst_icon);
                    RatingBar rating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.lst_ratings);

                    if(title!=null)
                    {
                        title.setText(o.title);
                    }
                    if(desc!=null)
                    {
                        desc.setText(o.desc);
                    }
                    if(dist!=null)
                    {
                        dist.setText(o.dist);
                    }
                    if(rating!=null)
                    {
                        rating.setRating(o.rating);
                    }
                    if(icon!=null) //edit mode
                    {
                        if(this.mode==1)
                        {
                            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dlet);
                        }
                    }
            }
            return v;
    }

}
```

In the OnClick method of the button I do the following:

```
CCAdapter mAdapter=new CCAdapter(context, R.layout.lisitem, CCS,2);
             MyList.this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             MyList.this.getListView().invalidateViews();
```

But after doing this only the 1st entry of the list have a delete icon others just show the default arrow icon.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake in the code the RatingBar and the ImageView is retrieved like this

```
ImageView icon=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lst_icon);
RatingBar rating=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.lst_ratings);
```

But these should be done like this

```
ImageView icon=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.lst_icon);
RatingBar rating=(RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.lst_ratings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
final CCcenter o = items.get(position);
```

You've declared it final... once it's set, you cannot ever change it, so you're stuck with that value being the first one you assign.  So I'm amazed your list isn't showing the same item over and over again.

Try removing the final declaration and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

make a inner static class to hold the refrence of your views like

```
static class viewHolder{
TextView title ;
TextView desc;
TextView dist;
ImageView icon;
RatingBar rating;

}
```

then in getview use something like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    viewHolder holder;
    if (v == null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.lisitem, null);
        holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ttl_txt);
        holder.desc=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.desc_txt);
        holder.dist=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dist_txt);
        holder.icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lst_icon);
        holder.rating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.lst_ratings);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    CCcenter o = items.get(position);
    if(title!=null)
    {
        holder.title.setText(o.title);
    }
    if(desc!=null)
    {
        holder.desc.setText(o.desc);
    }
    if(dist!=null)
    {
        holder.dist.setText(o.dist);
    }
    holder.rating.setRating(o.rating);
    if(this.mode==1)
    {
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dlet);
    }
    return v;
}
```